# JavaScript Object Creation Pattern

Tags: javascript, constructor, design-patterns, object-literal

I was reading an article here:

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/03/16/five-ways-to-create-objects/

It tells about five ways of creating objects. But my question is one of his way (3) is:

```
myApp.Notepad = function(defaultFont) {
    var  that = {};
    that.writeable = true;
    that.font = defaultFont;
    that.setFont = function(theFont) {
        that.font = theFont;
    }
    return that;
}

myApp.notepad1 =  myApp.Notepad('helvetica');
```

As per author, we can use it when multiple instances are needed we can use any pattern from 3 (above) to 5.

But as far as I know, we do need to use `this` keyword which reflects back newly created instances and refers to only that instance. However above, author uses `that` object instead of `this` and also there is no `new` keyword used above. How will it apply to multiple object instances ? Is it essentially same as using `this`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, `that` is a new object created by this line:

```
var that = {};
```

The function then proceeds to set the properties of this object.

On the other hand, `this` is used with a constructor function -- when called using `new`, a new object is automatically created and passed to the function as `this`. The same example could be written as:

```
myApp.Notepad = function(defaultFont) {
    this.writeable = true;
    this.font = defaultFont;
    this.setFont = function(theFont) {
        this.font = theFont;
    }
}

myApp.notepad1 = new myApp.Notepad('helvetica');
```

Comment: Thanks I know but what is advantage of using `that` object instead of using `this` constructor method?

Comment: @Dev555 - it's just a different (round about) way to "construct" an object. I don't know if there's an advantage to it, but a subtlety is that the `setFont` function uses a closure, instead of referring to the `this` object. `setFont` uses `that` which is defined outside of it. Syntactically, it's slightly less clear about what it's doing since it side-steps the `new` operator.

Comment: @Seth: That's what is confusion, waiting to see if things get clarified. Thanks

Comment: @Dev555: Seth has got the differences down for you. Also, the constructor method sets the prototype of the new object and allows prototype chaining, which is not possible with the `that` method. I don't really see any advantage of using the `that` method.

Comment: @Seth: well one major difference is that it would fail a `instanceof myApp.Notepad` check

Comment: Using a closure to reference an instance has a few issues. It's not very memory efficient since the scope chain when the object was created must be retained rather than being garbage collected. Also means methods can't be generic, calling them with some other value for *this* will operate on the original object, not the one passed to the function's *this*. Lastly, the name *that* doesn't give any hint as to what it actually is. I think it's much better to use *this* to refer to an instance and keep closures for cases where they are more efficient than alternatives.

Comment: I think these comments conclude that we should go with constructor pattern instead.

Answer (score 2):

One advantage of the using the object literal constructor (your code) that hasn't been pointed out yet is that when you are creating a new instance of an object, the `new` keyword is not necessary. Or in other words, if you simply *forget* to use the `new` keyword, your code will still run as intended as you are no longer relying on the use of the `new` keyword to give the scope of `this` to your newly created object in your constructor function; The `that` object is now taking care of the scope for you.

This is the approach that the YUI library (and Douglas Crockford) takes for constructors.

Consider the following simple constructor:

```
var Car = function(model){
  this.model = model;
};
```

If you were to call `Car('Dodge Viper');` or even `var MyCar = Car('Dodge Viper');`, the `this` in the function would actually refer to the global `window` object. So now the property `Model` above is actually a global variable, which is probably not what was intended.

```js
var Car = function(model) {
  var that = {};
  that.model = model;
  return that;
};

// Both work the same.
var MamsCar = new Car("Mini Cooper"); // with 'new'
var DadsCar = Car("Bugatti Veyron"); // without 'new'
alert("Mam's car is a " + MamsCar.model + " and dad's car is a " + DadsCar.model);
```